# What was the first programming language with Enumerations?

Tags: history, enum

I'm reading about Swift `enum`'s in the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html) guide and the text was comparing the differences between Swift's `enum` and C's `enum`. This made me curious as to where enumerations came from originally. I did search online before asking and even asked a few people and they *assumed* C. (I suppose I'm trying to confirm if enumerations came from C originally.)

What was the first programming language to include enumerations?

Comment: Swift's "enum" is actually a [union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably Lisp (1958).

In Lisp dialects, symbols can be used in the same way as C's enumerations. Indeed, the Wikipedia page for [Symbol (Programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_(programming)) says:

> In the most trivial implementation, [symbols] are essentially named integers (e.g. the enumerated type in C).

Scheme and Common Lisp have a `member` function, which can be used like:

```
(member 'b '(a b c))
;=> (b c)
```

Fortran also has an [enumeration type](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Typed+enumerators), but it looks like it was added in Fortran2003 for compatibility with C's `enum`, which itself was only added in ANSI C (1989).

Comment: In particular, you can define an enumerated type: `(deftype bool () '(member true false file-not-found))` (ref. [TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)). That can be used to check the type of your values with `typep`.

Answer (score 1):

In the strict sense, the answer is probably Pascal.
Pascal certainly had enumerated types before C did.
Algol 60, Algol W, Burroughs Algol, Simula 67, and
Algol 68, Pascal's more noteworthy predecessors,
did not.  In a somewhat weaker sense, COBOL "88-level"
definitions are not completely utterly and entirely
unlike enumerations; you could say that the germ of
the idea was there (more than in Lisp).

Comment: Can you [edit] in some references to back up your statement?